# AWS Athena External Table not returning data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I created an external table in Athena using the DDL script below. The table creates successfully in Athena but when I query it, it returns 0 rows.  The files in the s3 bucket specified are csv.gz files (there is one json file that I'm trying to exclude in TBLPROPERTIES).  The s3 bucket is in a different account then where I'm querying it from.  Supposedly the IAM role I'm using has access to read the data from the source S3 bucket in the other account.  Is there anything else I need to specify in the TBLPROPERTIES to make this work?  Thanks.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default_schema.customer_all(
  identity_line_item_id string, 
  identity_time_interval string,
  payer string,
  YEAR string,
  MONTH string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  payer string, 
  year string, 
  month string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://path/to/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1602464902', 'classification'='csv', 'exclude'='s3://path/to/data/*.json', 'delimiter'=',','compressionType'='gzip');
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is partitioned, and for partitioned tables you must either manually add all partitions, or configure [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) so that Athena knows where to find the files for each partition.

Adding partitions manually can be done with Athena DDL (i.e. SQL) or via the Glue Data Catalog API. I'll show you how to do it with DDL statements, because using the API is very verbose (although synchronous and faster, which suits some situations better).

You can add one or more partitions like this:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_all ADD IF NOT EXISTS
PARTITION (player = 'foo', year = '2020', month = '10') LOCATION 's3://path/to/data/foo/2020/10/'
PARTITION (player = 'bar', year = '2020', month = '10') LOCATION 's3://path/to/data/bar/2020/10/'
PARTITION (player = 'bar', year = '2020', month = '11') LOCATION 's3://path/to/data/bar/2020/11/'
```

The partition key values are given first, and then a location for that partition. Note that the partition location doesn't need to correspond to the values in the partition keys, your locations could be `s3://path/to/data/2020-10/foo/` if you want to (but keeping them looking similar is recommended for your own sanity, of course).

Using partition projection is often more convenient than manually adding partitions, but it has some limitations. Your partition keys must be enumerable, or ranges, which your `player` partition key is most likely not. There is a special partition projection key type that can use values injected from the query, though, and if all your queries contain a value for the player partition key, this configuration could work:

```
…
TBLPROPERTIES (
  …
  'projection.enabled' = 'true',
  'storage.location.template' = 's3://path/to/data/${player}/${year}/${month}',
  'projection.player.type' = 'injected',
  'projection.year.type' = 'integer',
  'projection.year.range' = '2020-2030',
  'projection.month.type' = 'integer',
  'projection.month.range' = '1-12',
  'projection.month.digits' = '2'
)
```

I can't promise that this will work as-is because there are things I don't know about your data. For example, I set the year to be a range from 2020 to 2030, I can't say if that's reasonable, you could set the end to 9999 if you want to, or 2022. I also don't know if your months are zero-filled or not, I assumed they were, but if they are not you need to remove `projection.month.digits` or change it to 1. I also assumed your data is organised on S3 like the pattern in `storage.location.template`, which might not be the case.

And to repeat what I said above: this partition projection configuration only works if all queries contain a value for `player`, otherwise you will get an error because Athena won't be able to figure out where to find the data – it can't enumerate over all possible values of `player`.

---

Some people will tell you to run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE customer_all` to load your partitions, but this is not something I recommend. Firstly it will only work if your data is partitioned using Hive style partitioning (e.g. `…/player=foo/year=2020/month=3/…`), and secondly it is very slow and inefficient. It works fine if you have a couple of partitions, but not if you have hundreds, and it's not a scalable solution to managing partitions.